# wxScintilla error compilation

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I got the following problem while using wxScintilla in wxwidget using codeblock and the environment is windows7.

obj\Release\GUIFrame.o||In function `GUIFrame':|
C:\editor\GUIFrame.cpp|44|undefined reference to`*imp*__ZN11wxScintillaC1EP8wxWindowiRK7wxPointRK6wxSizelRK8wxString'|

Please help me.

Comment: Looks like it might be a missing #include.  Please post the code around GUIFrame.cpp line 44

Answer (score 0):

The reported error is a linking error complaining that wxScintilla constructor (taking  wxPoint, ,wxSize, wxString related parameters) is not defined so you most likely need to add the wxScintilla library to your project.

Comment: well i built my wxScintilla using codeblock. And the built was successful but no wxScintilla.lib was developed. Instead there was an file named dummy in the lib directory. thanks...

Comment: Look at wxScintilla project settings or make some more general search checking wxWidgets specific directories.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. wxWidgets's got very low resources... I think wxwidget's developers must work on that...

Comment: I mean a search on your hard disk. If the compilation of wxScintilla was successful try to find wxScintilla.lib somewhere. Maybe there where wxWidgets libs are.